# print progress as looping through php class functions

Tags: php, apache, http

I am doing something with aOuth and some else's server at the moment and while the class I've created works it doesn't keep the HTML page posted of it's progress. For example say I have the following class:

```
class Something {
    function a() {
        sleep(2); echo "a()"; return TRUE;
    }
    function b() {
        sleep(2); echo "b()"; return TRUE;
    }
    function c() {
        sleep(2); echo "c()"; return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Then I loop through the class in my HTML:

```
$something = new Something();
if($something->a()) {
    if($something->b()) {
        if($something->c()) {
            echo "everything completed!!";
        }
    }
}
```

The page will render:

```
a()b()c()everything completed!!
```

6 seconds later. I want it to update as it goes (i.e. print `a()` when it's finished processing something->a(), print `b()` when it's finished processing something->b(), etc...)

Comment: But how can new object of that class will create after 6 second??

Comment: you'll have to ask that question again I'm afraid. It takes the page 6secs to appear because it takes 6secs to get throught the 3 functions (`sleep(2);`)

Comment: yes , first time it will work but after that how new object will creted automatically.

Comment: new `something` objects will not be created automatically

Comment: you are saying that after 6 second function a() should get executed. But how that happen if you will not call a() explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me in Chrome 21, Firefox 15 and IE8:

```
<?php
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

class Something {
    function a() {
        echo "a()" . str_repeat(' ', 1024); 
        ob_flush(); flush(); 
        sleep(2); return TRUE;
    }
    function b() {
        echo "b()" . str_repeat(' ', 1024); 
        ob_flush(); flush(); 
        sleep(2); return TRUE;
    }
    function c() {
        echo "c()" . str_repeat(' ', 1024); 
        ob_flush(); flush(); 
        sleep(2); return TRUE;
    }
}

$something = new Something();
if($something->a()) {
    if($something->b()) {
        if($something->c()) {
            echo "everything completed!!";
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: we have to persuade into starting an output immediately...

- PHP processor, with [ob_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)-[flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) combo.
- Apache (web-server), with sending `Content-Type` header right at the beginning of the script.
- web-browsers, as some of them won't consider drawing a partial output unless it's big enough. The workaround is to append a sizable, but empty string (`str_repeat(' ', 1024)`) to the output.

Comment: Thanks. I got a similar answer from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314

Answer (score 1):

Try flushing the output buffer each time you want the progress to be shown, with `ob_flush` function.

Each time you output some text, if output buffering is enabled, it is added to a buffer rather than being sent immediately to the client. When the request is done processing, the output is sent all at once.

If you flush the buffer, you force PHP to send the text it already have, without waiting for the request to complete.